# How to make first uploaded photo the user's avatar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using the CarrierWave gem and I have a `avatar_id` column on the Users table and a Photos table that has a `id` and `user_id` column. Is there a way to setup so the first photo uploaded by a User will be assigned to their `avatar_id`?

For example I sign up as User 56. I upload my first photo (id 89) and my `avatar_id` column updates with id 89.

Photos Controller:

```
  def new 
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    @photo.user = current_user
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photos."
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end



  def resize(width, height, gravity = 'Center')
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.combine_options do |cmd|
        cmd.resize "#{width}"
        if img[:width] < img[:height]
          cmd.gravity gravity
          cmd.background "rgba(255,255,255,0.0)"
          cmd.extent "#{width}x#{height}"
        end
      end
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end
  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    if @photo.update_attributes(params[:photo])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated photo."
      redirect_to @photo.gallery
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed photo."
    redirect_to @photo.gallery
  end

  def avatar
    if current_user.update_attribute(:avatar_id, params[:id])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully made Avatar."
        else
          flash[:notice] = "Avatar failed"
        end
        redirect_to(current_user)
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is starting to get more complicated than you probably want to dump in your controllers (start looking to [service objects](http://stevelorek.com/service-objects.html) to help), but here's what you'll want to do:

```
# photo created above
photo.user = current_user
if photo.save
  if current_user.photos.size <= 1
    current_user.avatar = photo
  end
  flash[:success] = '...'
  # ...
end
```

Another approach is to simply check to see if avatar is set yet, which is probably more appropriate, but I wanted to show you what you were asking for first.

```
current_user.avatar = photo if current_user.avatar.blank?
```

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel The second approach is only different in two ways: first is that the conditional is on the same line, and second is that it checks `avatar.blank?` vs `.photos.size`. The way to clean up this code is what I recommended at the top of my answer. ;)

Comment: Checking size is why I consider first solution ugly - it requires additional SQL query. As far as I understand OP's question, if there's no avatar, set first photo as an avatar. But we will perform that only on save, ergo, during first upload. If you minimize set of possible variables, you end up with the second solution! :)